# How to manually dismiss TouchScreenKeyboard in Unity

Tags: ios, keyboard, unity-game-engine

Title pretty much sums it up, I know I can bring it up with Open(), but I'd like something like .Close() to manually close it myself in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Unity docs of [TouchScreenKeyboard](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-active.html) you just need to have a reference to the previously opened keyboard (return value of Open) and then `TouchScreenKeyboard.active = false;`

Answer (score -1):

You can set they keyboard isntance to null.

For instance, if you had

```
keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open(...
```

then you can close it by doing

```
keyboard = null;
```